# Grouping result set data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure in which I would like to return a result set looking something like this:

```
id | student | term1 | term2
```

The problem is that the data isn't stored like this in the db. So the query will generate a result set looking something like this:

```
id | student | termNo | termValue
1  | lorem   | 1      | someValue
2  | ipsum   | 2      | anotherValue
```

Is there any simple way to convert this. The result sets is large, so I don't want to make several queries which would be the obvious solution.

Hope this is understandable =)

Comment: How many terms are there?....do you want it to be dynamic?

Comment: 4 terms exists, doesn't have to be dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, based on your comment, you can do this:

```
SELECT  id, 
        student, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN termNo = 1 THEN termValue END) term1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN termNo = 2 THEN termValue END) term2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN termNo = 3 THEN termValue END) term3,
        MIN(CASE WHEN termNo = 4 THEN termValue END) term4
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id, student
```

or

```
SELECT id, student, [1] AS Term1, [2] AS Term2, [3] AS Term3, [4] AS Term4
FROM YourTable T
PIVOT(MIN(termValue) FOR termNo IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) AS PT
```

Comment: Please correct "termNo = 1" statements to reflect correct values (1,2,3,4).  While the first code segment may be ugly (sorry), it does guarantee the more efficient query.

Comment: @Norla - Oops, apparently I suffered of a bad case of ctrl+c ctrl+v. Thanks for yor comment.